# Why isn't this HTML button functioning

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, dom-events

I am working through "Google Apps Script" by James Ferreira.

I have found several issues with code examples given so far and have been able to stumble my way through them.

I'm not great with HTML and this one has me stumped.

.gs

```
function startWorkflow() {
 var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('startWorkflow').evaluate()
  .setTitle('Start Workflow').setWidth(300)
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
  ui.showSidebar(html);
}
```

.html

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div>
<span>Let's get started with your workflow. 
First; 
Add an approver by entering their email address
in the Approvers box and clicking the add button.
When you are done adding appovers, click the Start Workflow button.</span>
</div>
<br>
<div>
<span class="sectionHeader">Approvers</span><br>
<div id="approvers"></div>
<div>
  <form id="addApprover">
    <input type="email" id="approver" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="submit" class="button blueButton" value="Add">
  </form>
</div>
<br>
<div class="center">
  <span id="startButton" class="button redButton">Start Workflow</span>
</div>
</div>

<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('styles').getContent(); ?>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
```

styles.html

```
<style type="text/css">

.sectionHeader {
 color: #202020 ;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-decoration:underline;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 }

.button {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-size: 12px;
 moz-border-radius: 3px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 padding: 3px;
 border:0;
 }

.blueButton {
  background-color: #3366FF;
 }

.redButton {
 background-color: #C80000;
}

.button:hover {
  opacity:0.7;
 }

.center {
 text-align: center:
}

#wrapper {
  margin:2px 4px 3px 4px;
  font-family: Verdana, Generva, sans-serif;
}

.reminder {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #3366FF;
  font-size: 10px;
  moz-border-radius: 3x;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 padding: 3px;
 }
```

The issue is with the "start workflow" button as I only have text.

Comment: It does nothing as you've not set any behaviour to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the the HTML you are referencing:

```
<span id="startButton" class="button redButton">Start Workflow</span>
```

The span tag *does* support events like `onclick` and `onmouseup`.  It would look like this:

```
<span id="startButton" class="button redButton" onmouseup="fncStartWorkFlow()">Start Workflow</span>
```

There needs to be a corresponding function in a `<script>` tag:

```
<script>
  function fncStartWorkFlow() {
    console.log('fncStartWorkFlow() ran!');
    //more code here
  };
</script>
```

Make those changes, then view the browser console to see if a message printed to the console.